# Is the function $f(z) = e^{-z^{-4}}$ holomorphic at $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Proof that function defined $f(0)=0$, $f(z) = e^{-z^{-4}}$ for $z \neq 0$, is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ but is not differentiable at $0$.

I have this question, and searched for an answer, and I saw these [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484098/is-this-function-holomorphic-at-0),
 [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291233/is-fz-exp-frac1z4-holomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236824/show-that-fz-exp-z4-z-neq-0-f0-0-satisfies-cauchy-riemann?rq=1). I use the Stein Complex Analysis book. 
To show that function is not differentiable at 0, I see that if I take $z=re^{\frac{i \pi}{4}}$ and apply the limit
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/ (re^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})^4}}{re^{i \pi/4}}$$
so
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/ (re^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})^4}}{re^{i \pi/4}} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{r^4}}}{r}.$$

I see that
$$(re^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})^4 = r^4(\cos 4\pi/4 + i \sin 4\pi/4) = -r^{4}.$$

But why $re^{i \pi/4} = r$?

Other question is, who I can proof that limit exist only using the limit properties? This is a singularity?

Thanks.

Comment: How'd you go from$$r^4(\cos(4\pi/4)+i\sin(4\pi/4))$$to$$r^{-4}$$?

Comment: It is certainly true that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)}{z}$ does not exist. However, neither does $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$, although you seem to implicitly assume that the latter is $0$. Perhaps because you've done something like $$e^{-0^{-4}}=e^{-(+\infty)}=e^{-\infty}=0$$ however, there is no such thing as $\pm\infty$ in $\Bbb C$ and, actually, for any $u\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ the equation $\exp(z)=u$ has arbitrarly large solutions.

Comment: Simply Beautiful Art: Sorry, I made a mistake, is $-r^4$ not $r^{-4}$